# Django - Save an uploaded image

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have a form where I am supposed to upload an image, but I can't get the image to save.  Everything else in the form works properly except the image.

I'm sure there are some issues with my `addGame` method, but I've tried it dozens of different ways with no luck.

I've gone through the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/file-uploads/), but it appears I'm still doing something wrong, as the image never gets saved.

(Just as a side note: I'm using Pillow for cropping the image, and I'm not sure if I'm doing that properly either, but I just added that in recently, and since the image doesn't save I have no way of knowing whether that is implemented correctly.  I'm leaving the cropping part commented out while I try to get the upload to work.)

`forms.py`

```
class GameForm(forms.ModelForm):

    image = forms.ImageField()
    code = forms.Textarea()
    deleteGame = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ('title', 'image', 'description', 'requirements', 'code', 'deleteGame')
```

`views.py`:

```
@login_required
def add_game(request):
    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GameForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            image = request.FILES['image']
            box = (200, 200, 200, 200)
            cropped = image.crop(box)
            form.image = cropped
            form.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/userprofile')
    else:
        form = GameForm()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['user'] = user
    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('addgame.html', args)
```

`models.py`

```
class Game(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='games', blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    requirements = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    code = models.TextField()
    deleteGame = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

My media settings look like this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

File Structure:

[image]

If I add an image via the admin portal, it saves properly, but I get an error like this in my log:

> Not Found: /media/games/Screen_Shot_2015-12-29_at_1.03.05_AM.png

Comment: You don't save the image to the database, you save it in your file system and store a path. You can access it from my_image_field.url.

Comment: So how do I save the image? By the way, it does NOT successfully get added to my media/games folder like it should.

Comment: What does your `MEDIA_ROOT` setting look like?

Comment: Just added the media settings as an edit.

Comment: If I add an image via the admin portal, it saves properly, but I get an error like this in my log: `Not Found: /media/games/Screen_Shot_2015-12-29_at_1.03.05_AM.png`

Comment: In your template, does the form tag have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: @RodXavier No, that is not included in my template.

Comment: The `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attributed is needed if you intend to send files along with the form data.

Comment: Ahhhh brilliant. You are a god.  If you add that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is needed in the `form` tag in your template if you intend to send files along with the form data.